# Gridview bigger first column Images

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

Hi I want to show grid of Images where first column should be the some of next two column,total 4 columns .Can anyone help me out this ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. First column should be larger than the next two columns or what do you mean?

Comment: Yes first column should be larger than next two

Comment: Using a gridview provides uniform column sizes; I don't know how you can do that;

Comment: I wants like asymetric gridview ,like screen shot 4 of that library

Comment: What library are you referring to?

Comment: Asymetric gridview library...https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView/master/screenshots/ss_4_cols.png